# I have a 24" bmx. I would like to know the make and model

Tags: identify-this-bike

I bought it as a complete bike. The forks are stamped fa. I figure free agent. The bottom bearing cup has a painted logo that says hammer. The numbers on the frame are
ACA09E005025.       09-010. I tried uploading a pic but it wouldn't. Says needs smaller image idk. [image][image]

Comment: "Please identify this bike that I haven't even given you a complete photograph of." We don't have a chance. (And, honestly, even with a clear photograph of the whole bike, we have a very low hit rate for BMXes.

Answer (score 0):

Does your logo look like this?   Then its a Hammer BMX logo.

[image]

Of course that log may have been added later, so there's no evidence its original.